# MySQL Dynamic Addition and Subtraction Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Price Table:

```
date       | price
------------------
2014-01-01   100
2014-01-02   20
2014-01-03   -30
2014-01-04   70
...
```

Is it possible to show a result table with a SQL query?

Result table:

```
date       | price  | total
--------------------------
2014-01-01   100     100
2014-01-02   20      120
2014-01-03   -30     90
2014-01-04   70      160
...
```

1. "Result table" is not an exist table its just sql result
2. "total" column should show the last status of customer's balance with addition and subtraction with previous row

Is it possible to write this SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date, 
       price,
       @total := @total + price as total
from (select date, price
      from your_table
      order by date) x
CROSS JOIN (select @total := 0) r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select date, 
       @total := @total + price as running_total, 
       price
from your_table, (select @total := 0) r
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pretty much standard SQL;

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(price) 
           FROM pricetable p 
           WHERE p.date<=pricetable.date) total
FROM pricetable
ORDER BY date;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/858d2/1).

...or a LEFT JOIN...

```
SELECT *, SUM(p2.price) total
FROM pricetable p1
LEFT JOIN pricetable p2
  ON p1.date >= p2.date
GROUP BY p1.date, p1.price
ORDER BY p1.date;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/858d2/5).

Comment: Good suggestion, but i think it effect bad performance on big table data, right? :/

Comment: @Kumul Since MySQL does not have analytic functions, I suspect the performance on this kind of query won't be optimal however you write it. I added a `LEFT JOIN` alternative which may improve performance, but the only way to tell for sure which is faster is to try it.